# Mac OSX - common commands not working

Tags: macos, terminal, smlnj

I'm new to using Terminal. Using common commands like date etc., throws an error "command not found". From what I've understood from the internet is that, my path is incorrectly set. SO I tried using  $PATH and it shows this -  /usr/local/Cellar/smlnj/110.82/: is a directory. 
What does this mean? also commands to uninstall smlnj is not working, it just shows "command not found"!

Comment: What exactly *is* your `PATH`? Enter `echo $PATH`, copy the result and paste it here and we might be able to help you correct it.

Answer (score 0):

> What does this mean?

In the terminal, `$PATH` expands to `/usr/local/Cellar/smlnj/110.82/`. The terminal expects to receive commands, but that is a directory

You've probably overwritten the value of `$PATH`, since it should include things like `/usr/env`, where commands like `date` etc. are stored. The easiest way to fix this would be to restart your terminal.